# Insert html from an external page on hover with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hover

I would like to insert html from an external file on hover with jquery.
This is my code:

```
$(".hoverCont").hover(function(){
var html = $(this).children().detach();
$(this).load(theme_directory + '/sections-html/home.html');
}, function(){
$(this).prepend(html); });
```

I can load the external html but I can't reinsert the previous html when the mouse leaves the div ... how can I do?

This is the code I need to save and replace ...

```
<div class="row hoverCont">
                        <div class="col-lg-9 d-flex flex-row p-5 minH hideDiv">
                            <div class="col-lg-5 d-flex">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <h2 class="p-2 bigH2 gray">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br /> consectetur
                                            adipiscing
                                        </h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                                        <p class="p-2 gray1">
                                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                                            tempor
                                            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                                            quis
                                            nostrud
                                            exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-3 d-flex backGray2 p-5 minH hideDiv hover">
                            <h2 class="p-2 bigH2 gray">
                                <span class="mb-3">Chi siamo</span>
                                <span class="secondH2">
                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
                                    do eiusmod tempor.
                                </span>
                            </h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And this is the html code from external file...

```
<div class="col-lg-6 d-flex flex-row p-5 minH">
    <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12">
             <h2 class="p-2 bigH2 gray">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br /> consectetur
                adipiscing
             </h2>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-12">
             <p class="p-2 gray1">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
             </p>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex backGray2 p-5 minH hover" style="background-image: url('http://ribel.local/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/ribelHover.jpg'); background-size: cover; ">
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 mb-5">
                <h2 class="p-2 bigH2 white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br /> consectetur
                                                adipiscing
                                            </h2>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 mt-5">
                <a href="" class="aStyle">
                                                Scopri chi siamo<br />
                                            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 mt-5">
                <a href="#">
                    <svg class="arrRight arrowWhite" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="84.866" height="14.709" viewBox="0 0 84.866 14.709">
                        <g id="arrow-right" transform="translate(-226 -16.716)">
                            <path id="right-arrow" d="M-4.482,4.9a.739.739,0,0,0-1.054,0,.744.744,0,0,0,0,1.044l5.346,5.346-81.587.039a.734.734,0,0,0-.738.739.743.743,0,0,0,.738.749l81.587-.039-5.346,5.336a.757.757,0,0,0,0,1.054.739.739,0,0,0,1.054,0l6.611-6.611a.726.726,0,0,0,0-1.044Z" transform="translate(308.516 12.042)" />
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sorry I was wrong to post an answer ..

Comment: Try to use `var html = ''` outside the hover event.. then inside hover use `html =` without `var`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Nothing changes...

Comment: `html` is scoped to the first method.  It is not going to be accessable in the second one.

Comment: mmh ... so how could I solve?

Comment: Put the `var html` outside the method, set it in the first method, and use it in the second one.  Or use a scoped down data attribute

Answer (score 0):

> Try to use `var html = ''` outside the hover event.. then inside hover
>   use `html =` without `var`

This is an Example

```js
var HTML = ''; // define the HTML outside the hover
$(document).on('mouseenter' , '.hoverCont:not(.mouseIn)' , function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    HTML = $this.html(); // updated HTML
    $this.addClass('mouseIn').html('<div>New HTML Loaded from Load function</div>');
    // when you trying to change the previous line to ,load 
    // $this.load(theme_directory + '/sections-html/home.html' , function(){ $this.addClass('mouseIn');  });
});
$(document).on('mouseout' , '.hoverCont.mouseIn' , function(){
   $(this).removeClass('mouseIn').html(HTML);
});
```

```css
.hoverCont{
  min-height : 200px;
  background : yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row hoverCont">
    <div class="col-lg-9 d-flex flex-row p-5 minH hideDiv">
        <div class="col-lg-5 d-flex">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h2 class="p-2 bigH2 gray">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,<br /> consectetur
                        adipiscing
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p class="p-2 gray1">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor
                        incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis
                        nostrud
                        exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 d-flex backGray2 p-5 minH hideDiv hover">
        <h2 class="p-2 bigH2 gray">
            <span class="mb-3">Chi siamo</span>
            <span class="secondH2">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed
                do eiusmod tempor.
            </span>
        </h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

<sup>I used `mouseenter` and `mouseout` events instead of hover to make it easier to control the events separately And I used `add/removeClass` in the code to prevent the HTML variable to catch the loaded html</sup>

Comment: Yes, I tried to do what you tell me. The problem is that I get a kind of flash effect, as if the inserted html goes in loop and when I move the mouse out of the div only the html inserted remains and I don't see the previous ...

Comment: @Luke  let me guess when you hover over the element the load trying to take effect and the height of the element decreased so the mouse go outside the element .. hover reads hover out so I think this is why its flashing .. try to fix the height of the element and try again or use `min-height` .. I'm not good in `detach()` but you can use `html = $(this).html();` instead of `children().detach()`

Comment: This way I don't have the flash effect but when I go out with the mouse from the div it doesn't load the previous html ...

Comment: @Luke answer Updated .. Please take a look

Comment: YES, now it works! Upload the saved HTML. But I have the problem that moving the mouse in the hover area sometimes makes the flash effect ... you can also see in your example if you try to go with the mouse on the text loaded ...

Comment: After some tests it freezes and no longer loads the saved html code ...

Comment: @Luke I think the problem is in `.load` for sure it will take a time to load the html structure in the element .. So use my code  and when you change to `.load` use the `.load` callback function to add the class . I will update my answer

Comment: Thank you for your help ... for me it is late now. Tomorrow I read your updated answer. You were very kind!

Comment: You're totally welcome @Luke .. I'm glad to help .. answer updated .. Have a great day :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! This solution works! Now load the saved HTML. The problem is that if with the mouse I pass over internal elements of hoverCont it makes the flash effect ...

Comment: Sorry @Luke for delay on reply I was little bit busy .. It'll be hard to guess from where the flash effect comes .. But try to play around the css and make sure you hover over the same height and the mouse didn't go outside the hoverCont element .. Also you may try another answers .. Hope you can find a solution soon .. Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid potential conflicts, you can use a data element to set the variable for each relevant hovered item.

```
$(".hoverCont").hover(
    function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.data('originalChildren', $this.children().detach());
        $this.load(theme_directory + '/sections-html/home.html');
    }
    , function(){
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.prepend($this.data('originalChildren'));
        $this.data('originalChildren', null);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed your `handlerOut` callback cannot see the `html` variable since it is defined in the `handlerIn` callback. You can either use the suggested method of declaring and initializing it outside `hover()` or use a data attribute as follows:

**Declare and Initialize**

```
var html = '';
$(".hoverCont").hover(function() {
  html = $(this).children().detach();
  $(this).load(theme_directory + '/sections-html/home.html');
}, function() {
  $(this).html(html); 
});
```

**Use a Data Attribute**

```
$(".hoverCont").hover(function() {
  var html = $(this).children().detach();
  $(this).data('html', html);
  $(this).load(theme_directory + '/sections-html/home.html');
}, function() {
  $(this).html( $(this).data('html') ); 
});
```

**Ref:**

1. https://api.jquery.com/hover/